# Why destructor invoked for the 'wrong' object?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have this code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int num)
    {
        this->num = num;
        std::cout << "Test constructed. Num = " << num << std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test& rhs)
    {
        num = rhs.num;
        std::cout << "Test copy constructed. Num = " << num << std::endl;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test destructed. Num = " << num << std::endl;
    }
    int num;
};


int main()
{
    {
        Test t = Test(1);
        t = Test(2);
    }
}
```

The code outputs:

```
Test constructed. Num = 1
Test constructed. Num = 2
Test destructed. Num = 2   <---- I hoped to have here Num = 1
Test destructed. Num = 2
```

Why is it in the third line of the output is like destructor invoked for the object with value 2 in the 'num' field ('2-num-object' for brevity)? Shouldn't it be invoked for '1-num-object'? We destroy '1-num-object' and instead of it we'll have '2-num-object' in the 't' variable. No?

Trying to comprehend it I even considered that '2-num-object' is on top of the stack, so it should be deleted first, before the '1-num-object', ok. But apart of this internals, after all, it's '1-num-object' destructed, so shouldn't the destructor with the value 1 in the 'num' field be invoked?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add an `operator=` overload and it will become clear what's going on.

Comment: What do you think assignment does? Do you think it will first destruct the destination (left-hand side) object? Why? What does your books, tutorials or other learning material say?

Comment: "We destroy '1-num-object' and instead of it we'll have '2-num-object' in the 't' variable. No?" No. You copy '2-num-object' into '1-num-object', leaving you with two identical but distinct objects.

Comment: Just a short suggestion on your test: Output the value of `this`, not the value of some member that might change. The object's address is much more reliable than the value of that member!

Comment: The important thing to remember is the _rule-of-three_: If you declare any of the destructor, the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator, then you very likely should be declaring all of them. You declare two of the three, but you don't declare the copy assignment operator. That's in 99% of cases going to give wrong or unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you want to see a more pretty output where the destructor runs on 1 and then on 2, you can use the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/509868)

Comment: Check **rule 035**. You must always follow this rule. Otherwise either of th following bugs will haunt you: 1. resource leak, 2. Double free, 3. Use after free. Be smart, be safe and follow the rule: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: The question smells of thinking like Java or C#-style object references , rather than actual objects

Comment: @Red.Wave — Sage advice. The OP's program declares a _destructor_ and _copy-constructor_, but fails to declare a _copy-assignment operator_. Best practice is probably to declare an `= default` version of the copy-assignment operator, thereby completing the the _Rule of Three_. In this case, however, the omitted declaration causes the compiler to supply a defaulted version, anyway. See Howard Hinnant's [famous chart](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf) from his 2014 ACCU presentation (slide 30). Of course, you know all this, and probably better than I do...

Comment: @tbxfreeware the `=default` will trigger the same problem as not declaring the operator. When the destructor is none-trivial, copy constructor and copy assignment must be defined carefully. You can `=delete` either one, in case in doubt. At least you won't be bumping heed to wall, detecting a mystery run-time bug; compile fails when you try to use the deleted function, and you learn that something is wrong. Even if you want a *logging* dtor, define all five special functions as *logging* ones, as well as every ctor in your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `Test` does not declare a *copy-assignment operator*. The rules are complicated, but in this case, the compiler will supply a default copy-assignment operator. That's because you do declare a *destructor* and *copy-constructor*. (See [slide 30](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf) of Howard Hinnant's 2014 ACCU presentation.)

The *compiler-supplied, default copy-assignment operator* does not call the destructor of class `Test`. Rather, it performs assignment on each member of class `Test` in turn. That means assigning member `num`, which is a simple integer assignment. No destructors are called in the process.

The destructor for variable `t` is not called until execution arrives at the closing brace of the block where `t` is defined.

The destructor of the temporary object created by `Test(2)` is called before that. It is called at the end of the *expression statement* where it appears, at the semi-colon (`;`) that ends that statement. Thus, the *lifetime* of the temporary ends at the semi-colon.

```cpp
int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "Allocating variable `t`...\n\n";
        Test t = Test(1);
        std::cout << "Assignment follows...\n\n";
        t = Test(2);  // <-- destructor for temporary `Test(2)` invoked at semi-colon.
        std::cout << "Assignment complete. Exiting block...\n\n";
    }  // <----------------- destructor for `t` called here.
    std::cout << "Outside block. Exiting function `main`...\n\n";
}
```

You can verify this by adding a user-defined copy-assignment operator to class `Test`. Inside it, check the address of the `this` pointer, to see which object had its `operator=` function called. You can also check the address of variable `rhs`. Similar checks of the `this` pointer should be made in the constructor and destructor functions.

With those changes, function `main` documents the following sequence of events.

```
Allocating variable `t`...

  Converting Constructor - object: 0, num: 1

Assignment follows...

  Converting Constructor - object: 1, num: 2

  Inside `operator=`, before assignment:
  rhs                    - object: 1, num: 2
  *this                  - object: 0, num: 1

  Still inside `operator=`, after assignment:
  rhs                    - object: 1, num: 2
  *this                  - object: 0, num: 2

  Destructor             - object: 1, num: 2

Assignment complete. Exiting block...

  Destructor             - object: 0, num: 2

Outside block. Exiting function `main`...
```

The first two lines show that variable `t` is allocated as `object 0`.

The next two lines show the allocation of `object 1`, which is the temporary object created by `Test(2)`.

`object 1` is deallocated prior to the message "Assignment complete." `object 1`, therefore, was destructed at the semi-colon which terminates the assignment.

`object 0` is not destructed until later, after the assignment is complete, and the block is being exited.

So, object 1, which is the temporary, is deallocated *before* object 0.

##### Details of the program

Looking at pointer values makes my eyes blur, so I created vector `object_id` to save them. Every time one of the constructors runs, I push the value of the `this` pointer onto the back of the vector. The subscript where a pointer is stored becomes its `id`.

Given a pointer, function `get_id` looks it up in the vector, and, if found, returns the subscript where it was found. If not found, function `get_id` returns `-1`.

Inside each of the critical functions, I added `get_id(this)` to the `std::cout` statement.

That gave me the following program.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test;
using ptr_t = Test const*;

std::vector<ptr_t> object_id;

int get_id(ptr_t const p)
{
    for (auto id{ object_id.size() }; id--;)
        if (p == object_id[id])
            return static_cast<int>(id);
    return -1;
}

class Test
{
    int num;
public:
    Test(int num) : num{ num }
    {
        object_id.push_back(this);
        std::cout 
            << "  Converting Constructor - object: " << get_id(this) 
            << ", num: " << num << "\n\n";
    }

    Test(Test const& rhs) : num{ rhs.num }
    {
        object_id.push_back(this);
        std::cout 
            << "  Copy Constructor       - object: " << get_id(this) 
            << ", num: " << num << "\n\n";
    }

    Test& operator= (const Test& rhs)
    {
        std::cout 
            << "  Inside `operator=`, before assignment: \n"
            << "  rhs                    - object: " << get_id(&rhs) 
            << ", num: " << rhs.num << '\n' 
            << "  *this                  - object: " << get_id(this) 
            << ", num: " << num << "\n\n";

        this->num = rhs.num;

        std::cout 
            << "  Still inside `operator=`, after assignment: \n"
            << "  rhs                    - object: " << get_id(&rhs)
            << ", num: " << rhs.num << '\n'
            << "  *this                  - object: " << get_id(this)
            << ", num: " << num << "\n\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout 
            << "  Destructor             - object: " << get_id(this) 
            << ", num: " << num << "\n\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "Allocating variable `t`...\n\n";
        Test t = Test(1);
        std::cout << "Assignment follows...\n\n";
        t = Test(2);  // <-- destructor for temporary `Test(2)` invoked at semi-colon.
        std::cout << "Assignment complete. Exiting block...\n\n";
    }  // <----------------- destructor for `t` called here.
    std::cout << "Outside block. Exiting function `main`...\n\n";
}
// end main.cpp
```

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it in the third line of the output is like destructor invoked for the object with value 2

Because when you wrote `t = Test(2);`, the *copy assignment* `Test & operator=(const Test &rhs)` is used with the right hand operand `rhs` as(bound to) `Test(2)` and left hand operand as `t`. Basically after this assignment, `t` is-a(has-a) copy of `Test(2)`. That is, `t.num = 2` after the assignment.

The **important thing** to note is that, after the assignment is done/completed, the object bound to the right hand operand `rhs` of the assignment operator `Test & operator=(const Test &rhs)` is destructed, which is why you get a destructor call saying `Num = 2`.

---

Now after this, `t` gets destructed and since `t`'s data member `num` was updated to `2` due to the assignment, you again get `Num = 2` in the output.

**This can be [seen](https://godbolt.org/z/eKjYjTP7E) more clearly** by adding your own copy assignment operator as shown below and printing out `this`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int num)
    {
        this->num = num;
        std::cout << "Test constructed. Num = " << num << " "<< this<< std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test& rhs)
    {
        num = rhs.num;
        std::cout << "Test copy constructed. Num = " << num <<  " "<< this<<std::endl;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test destructed. Num = " << num << " "<< this<< std::endl;
    }
    //added this copy assignment oeprator
    Test & operator=(const Test &rhs)
    {
      std::cout << "Inside copy assignment, rhs. Num = " << rhs.num << " "<< &rhs<< std::endl;
      num = rhs.num; 
      return *this;
    }
    int num;
};


int main()
{
    {
        Test t = Test(1);
        t = Test(2);
    }
}
```

Now the output will be:

```
Test constructed. Num = 1 0x7ffe051980d8
Test constructed. Num = 2 0x7ffe051980dc
Inside copy assignment, rhs. Num = 2 0x7ffe051980dc
Test destructed. Num = 2 0x7ffe051980dc
Test destructed. Num = 2 0x7ffe051980d8
```